# How would you translate "you have my vote" into German?

Tags: translation, expression

In English, you'd say to candidates that you'll vote for them. How would you say this in German? Something like:

> Hey Stefano, go for it. You have my vote.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Another common alternative:

> Meine Stimme hast du.

Comment: I prefer this word order because it emphasizes that I support the person's idea (stress on *meine*).

Answer (score 11):

To make it short:

> Meine Stimme ist Dir sicher.

Answer (score 9):

Wörtliche Übersetzung:

> Du hast meine Stimme.

Would be OK, but here are more ideas:

- Ich werde dir meine Stimme geben. // Dir geb ich meine Stimme
- Du bist mein Mann / meine Frau. (and implicit you add: *dem ich vertraue* or *auf den ich setze*)
- Auf dich setz' ich. (Note: *setzen* is the word for bet on the horses)

Answer (score 4):

Literally it means: `"You can count on me"` <sub>(no matter what, *if that person proofed to be trustworthy in the past*.)</sub>

- Du kannst dich auf mich verlassen.
- Du kannst auf mich zählen.
- Meine Stimme (Zustimmung) ist dir sicher.